# Nexus 3: Version clash for one artifact in two different repos of one group

Tags: android, maven, gradle, nexus3

In Nexus 3 (OSS 3.13.0-01) I created a group "public" which contains (besides others) the proxy repositories *maven-central* (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) and *atlassian* (https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/). Both of these repositories contain the artifact *com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android:analyticsapi*. If a Gradle build tries to get this dependency, it fails with "Could not find any matches for com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android:analyticsapi:[1.0.0,) as no versions of com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android:analyticsapi are available."

The maven-metadata.xml of the public group is as followed:

```
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
    <groupId>com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>analyticsapi</artifactId>
    <versioning>
        <latest>1.2.2-SNAPSHOT</latest>
        <release>1.2.1</release>
        <versions>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <version>1.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <version>1.2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <version>1.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </versions>
        <lastUpdated>20180315061158</lastUpdated>
    </versioning>
</metadata>
```

When I browse the repository, it contains the version 1.2.1.
[Browsing public repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnMtO.png)

So it appears to me, that the metadata of the Atlassian repo is parsed, and then the *latest* artifact is not found, because it is a SNAPSHOT and not available in maven-central. Both are configured to be Release repos, and the ordering inside the group places *maven-central* first and *atlassian* last.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the issue. The proxy repo "atlassian" was misconfigured as Release, I changed it to Mixed, and now the latest version was pulled.